# Является ли std::istream_iterator<int> trivially copy constructible?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, итераторы

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<std::istream_iterator<int>>);
```

Почему программа компилируется msvc, но не компилируется gcc/clang? https://godbolt.org/z/TfaeqWcMz

Согласно [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator), `std::istream_iterator<int>` должен быть *trivially copy constructible*.

Comment: Судя по всему, информация на cppreference.com устарела. Там ссылка есть: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0738r2.html

Comment: @Ariox в этом этом документе поменяли wording немного и перенесли из *Effects* в *Remarks*, но суть  на cppreference остаётся верной.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, согласно стандарту, `std::istream_iterator<int>` должен быть *trivially copy constructible*.

[[istream.iterator.cons]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/istream.iterator.cons#6):

> `istream_iterator(const istream_iterator& x) = default;`
>
> ...
>
> *Remarks*: If `is_­trivially_­copy_­constructible_­v<T>` is `true`, then this constructor is trivial.

[[meta.type.synop]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/meta.type.synop):

```
namespace std {
...
template<class T, class... Args> struct is_constructible;
...
template<class T, class... Args> struct is_trivially_constructible;
...
template<class T> struct is_trivially_copy_constructible;
...
template<class T, class... Args>
  inline constexpr bool is_constructible_v = is_constructible<T, Args...>::value;
...
template<class T, class... Args>
  inline constexpr bool is_trivially_constructible_v
    = is_trivially_constructible<T, Args...>::value;
...
template<class T>
  inline constexpr bool is_trivially_copy_constructible_v
    = is_trivially_copy_constructible<T>::value;
...
}
```

[[meta.unary.prop]/tab:meta.unary.prop](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/meta.unary.prop#tab:meta.unary.prop):

| Template | Condition | Preconditions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| ``` template<class T, class... Args> struct is_­constructible; ``` | For a function type `T` or for a *cv* `void` type `T`, ``` is_­constructible_­v<T, Args...> ``` is `false`, otherwise *see below* | `T` and all types in the template parameter pack `Args` shall be complete types, *cv* `void`, or arrays of unknown bound. |
| ... | ... | ... |
| ``` template<class T, class... Args> struct is_­trivially_­constructible; ``` | ``` is_­constructible_­v<T, Args...> ``` is `true` and the variable definition for *is_­constructible*, as defined below, is known to call no operation that is not trivial ([[basic.types]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/basic.types), [[special]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/special)). | `T` and all types in the template parameter pack `Args` shall be complete types, *cv* `void`, or arrays of unknown bound. |
| ... | ... | ... |
| ``` template<class T> struct is_­trivially_­copy_­constructible; ``` | For a referenceable type `T`, the same result as ``` is_­trivially_­constructible_­v<T, const T&> ``` , otherwise `false`. | `T` shall be a complete type, *cv* `void`, or an array of unknown bound. |
| ... | ... | ... |

[[meta.unary.prop]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/meta.unary.prop#8):

> The predicate condition for a template specialization
> `is_­constructible<T, Args...>` shall be satisfied if and only if the
> following variable definition would be well-formed for some invented
> variable `t`:
>
> `T t(declval<Args>()...);`
>
> ...

[[basic.types]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/basic.types#general-9):

> **Arithmetic types** ([[basic.fundamental]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/basic.types#basic.fundamental)),
> enumeration types, pointer types, pointer-to-member types
> ([[basic.compound]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/basic.types#basic.compound)),
> `std​::​nullptr_­t`, and *cv-qualified* versions of these types
> **are** collectively **called *scalar types***. **Scalar types**, trivially copyable class types
> ([[class.prop]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.prop)),
> arrays of such types, and cv-qualified versions of these types **are**
> collectively **called *trivially copyable types***. ...

Однако в [реализации gcc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stream_iterator.h#L75-L78) копирующий конструктор является *user-provided*, что делает его нетривиальным для любого типа.

```
istream_iterator(const istream_iterator& __obj)
: _M_stream(__obj._M_stream), _M_value(__obj._M_value),
  _M_ok(__obj._M_ok)
{ }
```

[[class.copy.ctor]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.copy.ctor#11):

> **A copy**/move **constructor** for class X **is trivial if it is not
> user-provided** and if:
>
> ...

`clang` и `msvc` в этом случае соответствуют стандарту. В вашем примере для `clang` вы не указали флаг `-stdlib=libc++`, поэтому по умолчанию использовалась стандартная библиотека libstdc++, что и в `gcc`. [Сравните](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:4,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:83,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:83,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:83,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:83,startLineNumber:4),source:%27%23include+%3Citerator%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Astatic_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v%3Cstd::istream_iterator%3Cint%3E%3E)%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%234%27,t:%270%27)),k:100,l:%274%27,m:49.99999999999999,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:clang1500,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:clang1500,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-stdlib%3Dlibc%2B%2B%27),(compilerId:clang1500,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-stdlib%3Dlibstdc%2B%2B%27)),editorid:4,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%234)+3/15%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:49.99999999999999,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

---

Интересно, что разработчик `gcc` опубликовал [LWG-3600](https://wg21.link/lwg3600), в котором предлагает убрать требование *trivially copy constructible* для `std::istream_iterator` из стандарта, т.к. изменение реализации поломает ABI libstdc++. На конец 2022 года этот *issue* решили принять, так что в ближайших стандартах ожидаем изменение ответа на противоположный.